# JavaScript put url value in href attribute + Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've an array of object

```
const arr = [
    {
        "crId": "10000112",
        "url": "https://test.metaverse.net/#/home?subTab=ceam_cm&request_id=10000112"
    },
    {
        "crId": "10000114",
        "url": "https://test.metaverse.net/#/home?subTab=ceam_cm&request_id=10000114"
    }
]
```

I'm listing comma separated values(crId) but its not parsing the `url `. I'm not sure what is the issue, when i hover over link it gives some weird url http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/%7B%7BcrMap.url%7D%7D

```
 const crList = arr.map(crMap => {
      return  '<a href="{{crMap.url}}" target="_blank">'+ crMap.crId +'</a>'
    }).filter(str => str.trim()).join(', ')
    return crList;
```

Comment: Your "weird URL" is clearly just having the _literal_ text `{{crMap.url}}` at the end, only URL-encoded. Not sure what exactly you expected to _parse_ those `{{...}}` in this context.

Comment: Either use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), if you want to get variables interpolated in there ... Or just remember that you already know a different way to insert a variable value into a string - the one you used for `crMap.crId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is parsing your URL. Why you think `crMap.url` should be treated differently from `crMap.crId`?

Add it the same way:

```js
const crList = arr.map(crMap => {
      return  `<a href="${crMap.url}" target="_blank">${crMap.crId}</a>`
    }).filter(str => str.trim()).join(', ')
    return crList;
```